# How To apply css properties in react native by using refs dynamically

Tags: xcode, reactjs, ios-simulator, react-native, refs

here is my instance 
I need to get the login div and hide it using refs 
How to achieve this ?

```
var Text=React.createClass({
componentDidMount:function(){
  console.log(this.refs.login.getDOMNode());

}, 

render:function(){
return (<View ref="login">
          <Text>Abc</Text>
          <Text>123</Text>
        </View>)
}
})`
```

Comment: Is this JavaScript? What are those XML literals?

Comment: there are no divs and there is no getDOMNode in react native

Comment: like setNativeProps  is there a way for gettting the data through ref(getNativeProps)
I need to get the Value entered from TextInput

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
render: function() {
    if(this.props.show) {
        return (<View ref="login">
              <Text>Abc</Text>
              <Text>123</Text>
            </View>)
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```